# Why does this function not modify the input list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, for-loop

For this assignment I'm not able to import modules, use any slicing, use string methods, or use list comprehension.

Now that that is out of the way, the idea is that I need to take an input list (matches), create a sublist every 3 items, then from those sublists remove each item that has an integer lower than 80, and append a heart to the highest number of the resulting list.

What I need to end up with with the following input:

```
matches = ["JS", "M", 90, "MS", "F", 76, "JB", "M", 89, "TM", "F", 79, "GM", "M", 100, "AB", "F", 65, "SK", "F", 88]
```

is an output of:

```
matches = [['JS', 'M', 90], ['JB', 'M', 89], ['GM', 'M', 100, '♥'], ['SK', 'F', 88]]
```

However my code results in an output of:

```
matches = ["JS", "M", 90, "MS", "F", 76, "JB", "M", 89, "TM", "F", 79, "GM", "M", 100, "AB", "F", 65, "SK", "F", 88]
```

And finally here is the code:

```
def findRecommendations(matches):
    matches_sublist = []
    matches_final = []

    for i in range(0, len(matches)):
        if i % 3 != 0:
            matches_sublist.append(matches[i])
        elif i != 0:
            matches_final.append(matches_sublist)
            matches_sublist = []
            matches_sublist.append(matches[i])
        else:
            matches_sublist.append(matches[i])
    matches_final.append(matches_sublist)
    matches_80_plus = []
    for i in range(len(matches_final)):
        if matches_final[i][2] >= 80:
            matches_80_plus.append(matches_final[i])
    final_max = 0
    for i in range(len(matches_80_plus)):
        max = matches_80_plus[0][2]
        if matches_80_plus[i][2] > max:
            max = matches_80_plus[i][2]
            final_max = i
    if len(matches_80_plus) > 0:
        matches_80_plus[final_max].append("\u2665")
        matches = []
        for i in range(len(matches_80_plus)):
            matches.append(matches_80_plus[i])
    elif len(matches_80_plus) == 0:
        matches = []
```

I understand most of it is done in a way that is really tedious since the constraints listed at the beginning, however it is part of a class assignment and I'm really stumped on where to go from here since the final list (`matches`) ends up not being modified.

Comment: I mean, your code doesn't modify the list you pass into it anywhere that I can see. Indeed, it probably shouldn't, since that is typically an anti-pattern

Comment: changes on `matches` inside `findRecommendations` doesn't alter the data on `matches` outside the function, one way to go around this is by adding an `return matches` at the end of the function, and then `matches = findRecommendations(matches)`

Comment: A simpler way to loop in groups of 3 is: `for i in range(0, len(matches), 3): for j in range(i, i+3):` then use `matches[j]` in the inner loop.

Comment: `matches = []` doesn't mutate the passed list. Instead, it causes the local variable `matches` to point to a whole new list. If you *really* want to empty out the passed list, you could use `matches.clear()` although I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga that this is typically a bad idea.